# Almost surely convergence and SLLN

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, law-of-large-numbers

I'm studying probability theory, especially about limit theorem. When I tried to solve a question, I got some trouble.

The problem is this:

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb E[X_1]=0$ and $\mathbb E[|X_1|^p]<1$ for some $1<p<2$. Show that
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{n^{1/p}}=0 \quad\text{a.s.} $$

At first, I tried with Strong Law of Large Numbers, but it fails.
I think that the condition "*expectation of $|(X_1)^p| < 1$*" is crucial, but I can't figure out what it means.

Please give me some advice!

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: This is a difficult problem, the idea is to use techniques from the classic Etemadi proof of LLN. You can define  $$Y_n= \left\{\begin{array}{cc} X_n & \mbox{ if $|X_n|\leq n^a$}\\ 0 & \mbox{else} \end{array}\right.$$ where $a$ is a small positive number chosen to ensure $Y_n\neq X_n$ at most finitely often with prob 1.  Then prove the result with $\tilde{S}_n = Y_1 + ... + Y_n$ using the fact that $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are uncorrelated and each has finite second moment.  Getting a tight bound on $E[Y_n^2]$ is crucial, clearly $n^{2a}$ works but that is not good enough.

Comment: And in fact it may be a good idea to first prove it under the assumption that the $X_i$ variables are nonnegative (as in the Etemadi proof), writing $X_i = X_i^+ - X_i^-$ to justify.